# What is Java Regex for checking "Must contain English Alphabets & Can contain either Digit /Dot/ Hyphen/ Space"?

Tags: java, regex, validation

I want to check if a name field meets these requirements:

-Must contain English Alphabets
-Can contain either Digit /Dot/ Hyphen/ Space

```
LuckStar12  : valid
Batman : valid
LuckStar-12 : valid
LuckStar.1 - 2 : valid
Luck Star 5 : valid

21212 : not valid cos it doesn't contain any English Alphabets
autó : not valid cos it contain "ó"
----- : not valid cos it doesn't contain any English Alphabets
```

This `"[a-zA-Z0-9\\s.-]+"` is to check if the name field has chars fall into these English Alphabets/ Digit /Dot/ Hyphen/ Space. However, it doesn't force "Must contain English Alphabets".

I tried `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[0-9\\s.-]` but it doesn't work.

So

What is Java Regex for checking "Must contain English Alphabets & Can contain either Digit /Dot/ Hyphen/ Space"?

Comment: name field not password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a [lookahead assertion](http://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9. -]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z]+)[A-Za-z0-9\s\.-]+$
```

The first part checks that there's at least one letter with look-ahead assertion. The second is just a set of characters you allow.

Comment: "\-" why we need "\"?

Comment: @Tum Got a bit overzealous with escaping. It's not needed but it didn't create harm either.

Answer (score -1):

[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9\s.-]*

{m} mean at lease m times match.

try it.

Comment: This will only work if letter is the first character.